# Unable to get input value in Razor Page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

Do you know what to put at the *asp-route-word*, I am not able to find it. This is my code:

```
<form class="d-flex" method="get">
   <input class="form-control me-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" id="searchWord" />
   <button class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit" asp-controller="Word" asp-action="Index" asp-route-word="???">
                        Rechercher
   </button> </form>
```

Here is the function in my controller:

```
public IActionResult Index(string? word)
    {
        if (word == null)
        {
            IEnumerable<Word> objWordList = _db.Words;
            return View(objWordList);
        }
        else
        {
            IEnumerable<Word> objWordList = _db.Words.ToArray().Where(w => word.StartsWith(w.NewWord));
            return View(objWordList);
        }
        
    }
```

So do you know how to get input text in order to pass it to my controller? I always get word null.
Thanks!

Comment: What's do you mean  get input value in Razor Page ? Is your project a razor pages  and you have a controller?  Where is your input text code in? a razor page  html or a view?

Answer (score 0):

> how to get input text in order to pass it to my controller

You can use `name` attribute to bind the input text, try the code like below:

```
<form class="d-flex" method="get" >
    <input name="word" class="form-control me-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" id="searchWord" />
    <button  class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit" asp-controller="Word" asp-action="Index">
        Rechercher
    </button>
</form>
```

result:

[image]

> what to put at the asp-route-word

You can put in the `<a ... ></a>` tag, read [asp-route-{value}](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-7.0#asp-route-value) to know more.

Like:

```
<a asp-controller="Word"
       asp-action="Index"
       asp-route-word="????">Send word</a>
```

result:
[image]